# How to convert from FP to OOP - Java Text Analysis

Tags: java, oop, methods, analysis

I have a school assignment that I wrote as a functional program in Java as opposed to Object-Oriented, but after looking at the requirements of the assignment, I now realize that it must contain various methods.

The program should be able to accept any text file with (.txt) extension and analyze it as stated:

*The program must be able to open any text file specified by the user, and analyze the frequency of verbal ticks in the text. Since there are many different kinds of verbal ticks (such as "like", "uh", "um", "you know", etc) the program must ask the user what ticks to look for. A user can enter multiple ticks, separated by commas - any spaces entered by the user before or after each tic must be ignored.*

*The program should output:*

*the total number of tics found in the text*

- *the density of tics (proportion of all words in the text that are tics)*
- *the frequency of each of the verbal tics*
- *the percentage that each tic represents out of all the total number of tics*

Here is my working code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class AssignTextAnalysis {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        double words = 0;
        int tickstotal = 0;
        System.out.println("Which file do you want to open?");
        // Initiate scanner to read files
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        String file = scnr.nextLine();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(".....Arbitrary path name....." + file));

        System.out.println("Which words do you want to search for?");
        String ticks = scnr.nextLine();
        ticks = ticks.toLowerCase();
        //So you can store the strings
        String[] array = ticks.split(",");
        int[] values = new int[array.length];

        // Use a for loop to add all the words into Values

        for (int z=0; z<array.length; z++){
            values[z] = 0;
        }

        //Use while loop to found out the amount of occurrences of the words
        while(input.hasNext()){
            String next = input.next();
            words++;
            for ( int y=0; y<array.length; y++){
                if ( next.toLowerCase().equals(array[y])){
                    values[y] +=1;
                }
            }
        }


        for ( Integer a : values){
            tickstotal +=a;
        }

         System.out.println("Total number of tics :"+ticks);
         double density = ((tickstotal/words)*100);
         System.out.printf("Density of tics (in percent): %.2f \n", density);

         System.out.println(".........Tick Breakdown.........");

        for (int z = 0; z<array.length; z++){
            System.out.println(array[z] + "\t/\t"+ values[z]+" occurences\t/\t"  + (values[z]*100/tickstotal) + "% of all tics");
        }
    }

}
```

Since I am new to Java, I am not sure how to convert it to OOP and would appreciate any help possible. Thanks all!

Comment: You might want to start by [extracting methods](https://refactoring.guru/extract-method).

Comment: That's not a functional program. It's regular old-fashioned imperative code. Functional programming does not mean that you use a method here and there.

Comment: I see no reason to write that in an OO style, and the description you posted doesn't hint at that being necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, for a small project like this, it would be a good idea to start by just making functions in order to make your code more readable.
Here is an example of functions you could make :

- `readFile()`
- `askTicks()`
- `calculateDensity()`

Try to think about what other functionality you could extract. Coding everything in the `main()` function is the best way to lose the complete meaning of your code as soon as you want to work on it again. It is way easier for you and for others to know which part of the code does what.

The next step to OOP will be to put each of these method in the class that is supposed to perform them, but it doesn't really seem obvious in your case since there are very few entites and actors.